# Series convergence question from baby Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Suppose, $a_n>0$, $s_n=a_1+\cdots +a_n$, and $\sum a_n$ diverges.  Prove that
>   $$\frac{a_{N+1}}{s_{N+1}}+\cdots\frac{a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}\ge 1-\frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}$$
>   and deduce that $\sum\frac{a_n}{s_n}$ diverges.

Looking for a verification of my proof.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{a_{N+m}}{s_{N+m}} &\ge\frac{1}{s_{N+k}}\sum_{m=1}^ka_{N+m}\\
& ={s_{N+k}-s_N\over s_{N+k}}\\
& = 1-\frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}.
\end{align}$$

Let $0<\epsilon<1$. Since, $\lim_{k\to\infty}1-\frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}=1$,
there is a $K\ge 1$, such that $k\ge K\implies 1-\left(1-\frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}\right)<\epsilon$; that is $\frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}<\epsilon$. So, it has been shown that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\ge 1$,
$\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{a_{N+m}}{s_{N+m}}>1-\epsilon$. Therefore the series does not meet the Cauchy criterion and diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof that $$\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{a_{N+m}}{s_{N+m}} \geq 1 - \frac{s_N}{s_{N+k}}$$ looks correct, except that I think, technically, since $a_n > 0$ and hence $s_{n+1} > s_n$ for all $n$, $$\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{a_{N+m}}{s_{N+m}} > \frac{1}{s_{N+k}} \sum_{m=1}^k a_{N+m}.$$  So strictly greater with no chance for equality.  You also may want to remark the (slightly obvious point) that $s_{n+1} > s_n$ beforehand, for completeness.

As for the second part of the proof, maybe you could be a bit more explicit and say why the series does not meet the Cauchy criterion?  I.e. you could say that an $\epsilon > 0$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily due to what you've shown.

In other words, your argument looks good and I'm only saying that you could (optional!) explain your steps in a more complete manner.

Comment: Thanks Clark, and thanks for the tips.  I am doing these excercises only for my own benefit though.

Comment: I've been there before!  After reading your proof I knew that you had the core concept down, so the only thing left was completeness.  If you're doing these exercises for your own benefit, though, you are right, airtight completeness might not be the best use of your time.  Good proof!

Answer (score 1):

Here may be an intuitive way to think about it. Assume the sequence is convergent, I claim that there exist some $\epsilon$ such that for all $N>0$, there exists terms 
$$
\sum^{n}_{i=m}\frac{a_{n}}{s_{n}}\ge \epsilon, n>m> N
$$
Therefore the sequence is not convergent and it must diverge. To see the claim I made, since we know $s_{n}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, for any sufficiently large $N$, we can decompose $s_{n}=s_{N}+\sum^{N}_{i=n+1}a_{i}$. Since the $s_{N}$ factor is going to be relatively small in contrast to $s_{n}$ with $n\rightarrow \infty$, it is enough to choose enough factors from the sum to get $$\sum^{n}_{i=m}\frac{a_{i}}{s_{i}}\ge \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=m}a_{i}}{s_{n}}\ge \epsilon$$
And I think this is essentially what Rudin's hint and your proof is about. Of course this kind of result would not hold if $\sum a_{i}$ converges, as the sum would converge as well.

Comment: Do you mean $s_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?.

Comment: Yes, you know $a_{n}\ge 0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ diverges.